# Bits on the Run API - Can not delete the video

Tags: video, video-streaming

I'm using **Bits on the Run API**, the video hosting component to manage video, player ... (similar to youtube, vimeo)
 I had post this question in **Bits on the Run forum** in [**here**](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/bits-on-the-run/system-api/36746/can-not-delete-videos)

But I re-post this question here to make it more clear.

**I have a problem when deleting video**. I **can not delete any video** in my list videos. But I can manage videos, I can update information video by function $botrAPI->call("/videos/update", $params);

Here is error that I caught:

```
array
(
    'status' => 'error'
    'message' => 'video_key: Video with the key rpmbRU62 does not exist'
    'code' => 'NotFound'
    'title' => 'Not Found'
)
```

I sure that I can get and update information by video_key is `rpmbRU62`.

My function to delete video:

```
 public static function deleteVideo($key)
    {
        $botrAPI = self::getInstance();
        $params  = array('video_key' => $key);
        $response = $botrAPI->call("/videos/delete", $params);
        dump($response);
        if ($response['status'] == "error") {
            return array(
                'status'  => $response['status'],
                'message' => $response['message'],
                'code'    => $response['code'],
                'title'   => $response['title'],
            );
        }


        return array(
            'status' => $response['status'],
        );
    }
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.